# Scaffolding error with CodeIgniter_2.1.2

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using codeigniter 2.1.2 and I want to use scaffolding feature to add information to table. When I set this `$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = 'scaffolding';` in routes.php and call it in controller  `$this->load->scaffolding('applicants');` I get the following Error:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::scaffolding() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmplatform\application\controllers\Applicant.php on line 6** So I am asking if I can find a library that contains scaffolding features because in this version I downloaded from GIT there is no scaffolding folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffolding was depreciated in codeigniter. It isn't longer offered. The tutorials are outdated, so I'm guessing this is where you saw it?

Comment: I was following video tutorial but when I try to read instructions about this new version it has been deprecated as you said. Thanks.